# Traefik 2.4 - http not found, but https works

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm using Traefik 2.4 via docker-compose for development server. Here's config

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --api=true
      - --api.dashboard=true

      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsEncrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsEncrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      # - "--certificatesresolvers.letsEncrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsEncrypt.acme.email=$ACME_EMAIL"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsEncrypt.acme.storage=/certs/acme.json"
    restart: always
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    env_file:
      - .env
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints: web,websecure
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule: Host(`monitor.$DEFAULT_HOST`)
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver: letsEncrypt
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.service: api@internal

      traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme: https
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares: redirect-to-https
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./custom/:/custom/:ro
      - ./certs/:/certs/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "traefik-whoami"
    restart: always
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints: web,websecure
      traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule: Host(`whoami.$DEFAULT_HOST`)
      traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver: letsEncrypt

      traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme: https
      traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares: redirect-to-https

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: $DEFAULT_NETWORK
```

I'm using flags configuration on purpose, because it's easier to configure using ENV variables.

As you can see, I have 2 entrypoints: `web` and `websecure`. And on my target service (`whoami`) I've configured both those entrypoints: `traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints: web,websecure`. I've seen here, that somebody uses different routers for http and https, but this way of configuring seems weird: Traefik supports configuring multiple comma-separated entrypoints for same router, and it even shows them in UI:
[image: Multiple entrypoints for same router]

It works almost fine, especially for HTTPS, **BUT** if I'll try to open it the same resource via HTTP, it results in `404 page not found`

Example:

1. Try to open `https://monitor.MYDOMAIN`, and it successfully proxying traffic
2. Try to open `http://monitor.MYDOMAIN`, and it will show `404 page not found`

This problem is not only appears for Traefik Dashboard, but for any type of router, `whoami` and any other mine projects

If Traefik supports configuring multiple entrypoints for same router, I expect it to work from both those entrypoints